# Why am I getting a Parse Error in my smart contract after the constructor?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, dapps, ethereumj

I'm writing a token sale smart contract & my original error was my function had the same name as the contract and I changed it to a constructor because the contract cant have the same name as the function. I know get this error

```
browser/ballot_test.sol:11:17: ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
constructor ChampToken(ChampTokenSale _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
^--------^
```

Here is my code -

```
constructor ChampTokenSale(ChampTokenSale _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) 
 public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }
```

Comment: If you are creating a crowdsale you may want to look at OpenZeppelin Contracts to see if this meets your needs. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: Thanks I will look at the docs, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The constructor doesn't take a name.

Change your code to:

```
constructor (ChampTokenSale _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public { 
    admin = msg.sender; 
    tokenContract = _tokenContract; 
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice; 
}
```

(See "Creating Contracts" in the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/contracts.html?highlight=constructor#creating-contracts).)